# htaccess redirect to subfolder results in too many redirects

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, laravel-routing

I am currently working with some software called [sendy](https://sendy.co/). I want to redirect the url mydomain.com/sendy to the sendy folder in the root directory. I am using Laravel on a shared account with other htaccess configurations after the one below. I put the sendy redirect first as a result. However I get the error

```
The website has a redirect loop
```

I am no expert on .htaccess files so any help would be great as to what may be causing the issue. What I have currently now is shown below:

```
# Use PHP5.4 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php

#AddType application/x-httpd-php54 .php


RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?sendy/ /sendy/? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ public/index.php [L]
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is intent behind this rule? This is definitely redirect loop since you're redirecting `/sendy` to `/sendy`

Comment: To access the folder sendy, and to not redirect using the configurations below(the dotted lines) which are for Laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To ignore folder `sandy` from rules below just use this rule instead:**

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /sendy [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this still points me to the laravel routes. I added the whole file to the question in hopes this will help

Comment: ok check updated rule and make sure this is still very first rule below `RewriteEngine` line.